# why is 12345 read into an integer array as one value of 12345 instead of five values 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5?

Tags: c++

I just started learning c++ and this is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int a[5];

  for(int i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++)
  {
    cin >> a[i];

    if (a[i] % 2 == 0)
    {
       cout << "the number" << a[i] << "is even" << endl;
    }
    if(a[i] % 2 != 0)
    {
       cout << "the number" << a[i] << "is odd" << endl;
    }
  }
}
```

Ihen I input 5 number like (12345) and build it, it only shows eg: (the number 12345 is even).I don't understand why does't it work right.

Please tell me what's my mistake.

Comment: Separate the digits with spaces.

Comment: Also, please [edit] your question title to something meaningful. It should describe the issue you're having clearly, in a way that will be useful to a future user of the site who is scanning a list of search results looking for a solution. Your current title provides nothing that is meaningful or useful to those users. Thanks.

Comment: I don't know whether I understand your question right, but do you input 12345 once, or 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 successively? You tell your program once in a loop to ask you for a number.

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but you absolutely need to indent your code correctly. For example like the samples in your C text book. I edited your question and did it for you.

Comment: And also: why do you store the numbers in an array? You're not using the array at all. You could replace `a[i]` and `a[5]` with say `number` and your program would give the same result.

Comment: [Your code](https://www.ideone.com/chRswE) works fine.

Comment: This code really doesn't need the array. It could just use a single int value to store the input.

Comment: @ Jabberwocky it was an exercise and it says that store your numbers in array.

Comment: @Sunburst275 that was my problem. i inputted 12345 first. then i inputted 1 2 3 4 5 and it worked. but i don't know exactly why.

Comment: @kiarash what would you type if you wanted to input the number `10000`?

Comment: @kiarash If you input "12345", your program interprets it as a whole number, namely: "twelvethousand threehundred and five". Your program does this: It asks you for a number and then tells you whether it's even or not. Then it does the same, five times in a row. So it evaluates the number you input immediately.

Comment: `>>` usually reads one token from the stream. For an `int` that's one number. It will keep reading until the number can't possibly be a number, it finds a space or a non-digit for example, 12345 is easily readable as a single number, so it is read as a single number .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The string "12345" represents the integer twelve thousand, three hundred and forty five. So when you read that string using regular integer rules, that's the integer you get.

Either produce a string the encodes multiple integers under standard rules (like "1,2,3,4,5" or "1 2 3 4 5") or write your own routine to parse the input according to whatever rules you want.

If it worked the way you suggest, how could you ever read in an integer greater than nine?

Comment: Or he could just - like what the program actually does - input the values successively. lol